# How to continue script execution after a command replaces itself with a new shell process?

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell

I have an executable ruby script as follows:

`example`:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
at_exit do
  # Replace the currently running Ruby process with a new instance of the parent shell 
  exec(`ps -p #{Process.ppid} -o comm=`.chomp)
end
```

It works fine when running as a command, but due to it replacing itself with a new shell instance, it does not work in scripting, as no commands after it are executed.

How do I modify my shell script such that execution continues?

(I am running the shell scripts like so: `bash test.sh`)

Some examples of what I would like to achieve:

`test.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
./example && echo "How do i get here"
```

`test1.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
VAR=foo
$VAR ./example <argument>
```

`test2.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
cd ~ && git clone https://github.com/gfxstrand/pycook
yes | ./example
```

`test3.sh`:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash
./example || echo "How do i get here"
```

Note that I cannot change the behavior of the ruby script-- it must replace itself with a new instance of the parent shell at exit. (The exception to this is a solution replacing the parent process of the ruby script with a new instance of the parent shell, which would also suffice)

Comment: The new shell is running in the same child process as the original ruby script. It will continue with the original script when you exit from the new shell.

Comment: Creating both the `example` file and the `test.sh` file, marking them both as executable, and running `bash test.sh` does not output "How do i get here", at least on my machine. What are you doing differently?

Comment: Are you sure `./example` exits with zero?

Comment: I believe so-- I have added an additional testcase to account for the possibility it does not, (`test3.sh`), and that also does not output "How do i get here".

Comment: OK, now I get it. After `bash ./test.sh` if I press Ctrl+D it does print `How do i get here`. If you want the rest of the script to run inside the interactive shell `./example` replaces itself with I don't think that's possible.

Comment: I'm not too hung up on the rest of the script running inside the newly created shell, I just want the rest of the script to run at all. Ctrl+D also works in my testing, but unfortunately I cannot rely on user interaction for my purposes.

Comment: But what's the point?

Comment: `example` is, as the name suggests, a simplified example. My real-world use case has a ruby script which has the same exit behavior as `example`, but is an actual program. I wish to run this program in a script, and run additional commands after it.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea. Try `./example </dev/null && whatever` then.

Comment: Do you **need** the exit code of `example`? I would be surprised that a program with such a bizarre behaviour as _example_ would actually set a meaningful exitcode.

Comment: What happens if you run it in your script as `( ./example )` or as `(sh -c ./example & wait)`?

Comment: I do need the exit code of `example`, yes, and I cannot edit it.

Comment: Running it as `( ./example )` does not work.

Comment: Running as `(sh -c ./example & wait)` does work! Would you mind submitting that as an answer @user1934428?

Comment: `./example </dev/null && whatever` also works! Would you mind submitting that as an answer @oguzismail?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the simplest solution, but

```
(sh -c ./example & wait)
```

should work. After `example` replaces itself with the parent `sh` process, this process will then immediately end, and the grand parent won't be bothered.